# How to fix dependencies problems when installing firebase in my project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, security, npm, dependencies

I have a Vite React.js app, and I want to connect it to Firebase. However, when I try to install it, some errors pop up in the terminal. The audit fix throws me this:

## npm audit report

protobufjs  6.10.0 - 7.2.3
Severity: high
protobufjs Prototype Pollution vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-h755-8qp9-cq85
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/protobufjs
@grpc/proto-loader  0.6.0-pre1 - 0.6.13
Depends on vulnerable versions of protobufjs
node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader
@firebase/firestore  <=0.0.900-exp.f43d0c698 || 2.3.7-202151602035 - 2.3.7-canary.f6e1645ef || >=2.3.8-20216122160
Depends on vulnerable versions of @grpc/proto-loader
node_modules/@firebase/firestore
firebase  0.900.22 || 7.9.1-0 - 7.9.1-canary.0396117e || 8.6.8-202151602035 - 8.6.8-canary.f6e1645ef || >=8.7.0-20216122160
Depends on vulnerable versions of @firebase/firestore
node_modules/firebase

4 high severity vulnerabilities

What can I do? (It is the first time that I have tried to install Firebase on this computer.)

I have only tried the audit fix and audit fix --force commands because I literally don't know much else.

Answer (score 0):

I probably know as much as you, but I found https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7431 which seems to indicate that it's an ongoing issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).